# How do I specify a file type for importing .obj files?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidocumentbrowservc

I'm trying to get my app to recognize [.obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files for importing.

I've tried to follow the instructions in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/216/).

I've tried specifying as both an Imported UTI, and an Exported UTI. Neither causes the file to be openable in `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` (the document icon is grayed). I don't understand how my native document format is openable in the browser either. I've tried deleting and reinstalling the app from the device.

**What am I missing? Why isn't this simple?**

Here's what I've got:

[image: Xcode Document Types]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out iOS already knows about .obj files. On macOS, I ran the following:

`mdls myfile.obj`

Which among other things shows:

```
kMDItemContentType                 = "public.geometry-definition-format"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
    "public.content",
    "public.geometry-definition-format",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.3d-content"
)
```

So the UTI is `public.geometry-definition-format`. I don't know if that already specifies the extension or is a more generic type.

The following worked to make the files openable in `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`:

[image]

The UTI isn't declared in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1) (what a surprise!), so I'd recommend using `mdls` to look up UTIs.